# Typescript - Extract a unique values from a nested array to a new structurize nested array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I currently want to extract in this array:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2021-04-21",
      "time":"05:12",
      "status":"Collected",
      "caption":"Parcel collected"
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-08-21",
      "time":"12:04",
      "status":"Awaiting Collection",
      "caption":"Parcel is awaiting collection"
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-08-21",
      "time":"12:03",
      "status":"In-transit",
      "caption":"Parcel is in-transit"
   }
]
```

to transform to this array whereas i check on the date and time for the new nested array like this:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2021-04-21",
      "time":"05:12",
      "status":"Collected",
      "caption":"Parcel collected"
   },
   {
      "date":"2019-08-21",
      [
         {
            "time":"12:04",
            "status":"Awaiting Collection",
            "caption":"Parcel is awaiting collection"
         },
         {
            "time":"12:03",
            "status":"In-transit",
            "caption":"Parcel is in-transit"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have tried filter and reduce but will be much same as initialized array as it takes the whole [i] as unique and not date as unique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As in your snippet, you need to store nested data in some kind of container. I've named it `data`.

```js
const array = [
  {
    date: "2021-04-21",
    time: "05:12",
    status: "Collected",
    caption: "Parcel collected",
  },
  {
    date: "2019-08-21",
    time: "12:04",
    status: "Awaiting Collection",
    caption: "Parcel is awaiting collection",
  },
  {
    date: "2019-08-21",
    time: "12:03",
    status: "In-transit",
    caption: "Parcel is in-transit",
  },
];

const result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex((o) => o.date === curr.date);
  if (index !== -1) {
    const { date, ...rest } = acc[index];
    const existTime = curr.time;
    const existStatus = curr.status;
    const existCaption = curr.caption;
    if (!rest.data) {
      acc[index] = {
        date: date,
        data: [
          { ...rest },
          { time: existTime, status: existStatus, caption: existCaption },
        ],
      };
    } else {
      acc[index].data.push({
        time: existTime,
        status: existStatus,
        caption: existCaption,
      });
    }
  } else {
    acc.push({ ...curr });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, it works greatly as per requested. Thanks! May I ask if you can explain more on this since I'm new with this:

`const index = acc.findIndex((o) => o.date === curr.date);
  if (index !== -1) {`

Comment: `acc` is an array and you are finding it and return `index` if any satisfy the condition `o.date === curr.date`. If it exist then it will return its index else return `-1`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex